# Matching of $ in ICU

Tags: regex, icu

Given the `UnicodeString`, `s`, containing `"Mary\n"` and a `RegexMatcher`, `m`, compiled with the pattern `"Mary$"`, if I do:

```
m->reset(s);
bool b = m->find() != 0;
```

then `b` gets set to `true`.  Why?  The pattern says that the `'y'` of `"Mary"` should be at the end of the string.  In this case, it's not the end of the string -- the `'\n'` is.  It should be set to true only if the `UREGEX_MULTILINE` option were set.  Right?

This is using the C++ ICU version 4.8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior: `$` matches at the end of the string or line (depending on the `(?m)` or `MULTILINE` flag) *before* any trailing newline. See [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) on anchors (scroll down about halfways to "Strings ending with a line break").

Use `\z` instead - that only matches at the very end of the string.

Comment: Just to be clear: are you saying that ICU always matches before any trailing newlines regardless of the MULTILINE flag?

Comment: Yes, all regex engines do so. I should probably write "newline" instead of "newlines", though (I'm used to the plural form because of Windows, where we've got two characters for newline), and without the multiline flag, `a+$` will not match `"aaa\n\n\n"`.

Comment: Thanks. Just as an FYI: the regex semantics for XQuery (based on XPath) state that $ matches only the end of a string (when MULTILINE is off), i.e., newlines are considered ordinary characters. (I'm working with XQuery which is why I know this.)  Shame it's different.